# MATLAB List values above threshold

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix. I can use the below code to find the number of elements above 1.61. How can I actually list the elements that are above 1.61 and show what value they are? for instance, if I have a value of 8.1 and 9.1, I would like Matlab to tell me those two values. Can I do that?

```
for i = 1:5
     A = ans.atom_data(:,5,i);
     count(i,:) = sum(A(:)>1.61)

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to know the values, use logical indexing, like this:

```
result = A(A>1.61);
```

If you want to obtain the result for each third-index-layer of a 3D array `B`, you can do it with cells:

```
result = cellfun(@(x) x(x>1.61), squeeze(mat2cell(B,size(B,1),size(B,2),ones(1,size(B,3)))),'uni',0);
```

Then `result{1}` gives the values corresponding to `B(:,:,1)`, etc.

Comment: One slight problem, it only does it for the last matrix. IT is a 3D matrix so multiple 2D inside. How can I list value all the values/

Comment: @JacksonHart: This will return *all* of the values greater than 1.61 in your 3-D array. However, it returns them as a single column vector.

Comment: @horchler How can I return the values from the matrix, second, and so on?

Comment: @JacksonHart See updated answer and tell if that's what you need

Comment: @LuisMendo that did not seem to work, it gave me some error:Warning: Number of input vectors, 3, did not match the
input matrix's number of dimensions, 2. 1 trailing
singleton input vectors were removed. 
> In mat2cell at 83
  In matrix at 6

Comment: @JacksonHart The second part only works if `A` is a 3D array. So maybe you should apply it to your `ans.atom_data` (which appears to be 3D), not to `A`